# Eclipse Mac OS X Debug Error: "FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)"

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

```
ERROR: transport error 202: gethostbyname: unknown host
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
```

OS: Mac OS X 10.10.2 MacBook Pro with Retina Display
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

I'm not sure why debug is failing and resulting in these errors. I haven't changed/updated anything that I can recall.

Any advice? I realize this question has already been asked, but not for Mac OS X and the answers were unclear for me. What should I try?

Comment: Can you ping locatlhost as in: ping 127.0.0.1?

Comment: This is the readout: 
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms
...

Comment: --- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
176 packets transmitted, 176 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.038/0.106/0.225/0.041 ms

Answer (score 19):

I had exactly the same issue (on OSX), in my case the line in /etc/hosts was commented out:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

It's explained in Eclipse Wiki: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debug/FAQ#I_can_run_a_program_but_not_debug_it.3F.3F.3F

Comment: I typed sudo nano /etc/hosts and then I found out I modified localhost to some name. So, I corrected name as localhost. It's work!

Answer (score 5):

**Resolved Issue by editing /etc/hosts file:** I also had similar issue(Able to ping 127.0.0.1, but issue while pinging localhost, debug from eclipse not working). I resolved it by removing entries like ::1 localhost, ff81::1%lo0 localhost with only 127.0.0.1 localhost.... I removed rest of the entries for localhost. I did this for my mac.

After this process I can debug my java application using eclipse.

*Sometime, what ever information that I given is not working. In that case, I just moved the file /etc/hosts file to hosts_backup. then restored the file. ie moved file hosts_backup to /etc/hosts. then it starts working. Don't know how it is working. But it resolved my issue*