# Wildfly 8.2 does not start: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Tags: java, jvm, wildfly

I am using Eclipse Neon with integrated Wildfly 8.2. The server however does not want to start because of the message:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
ERROR: transport error 202: gethostbyname: unknown host
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @FedericoSierra - that one is about port conflicts. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188789/eclipse-mac-os-x-debug-error-fatal-error-in-native-method-jdwp-no-transports) is the duplicate.

Comment: stdunbar, I am using Windows 7. @FedericoSierra  thank you, I will check it